# Aligning buttons and labels with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a program to display user data in a GUI from the game called `'osu!'` to practice making GUIs and accessing APIs (and handling data between databases and modules but that's not relevant here).

I've got a for loop to place a back button in the top left of all the frames that aren't the menu. These buttons are placed in column 0 and row 0.

Now that I've started to fill in the contents of the frames I've noticed that the columns width is the same as the width of the widest row, the problem now being that anything in column 0 that makes the column wider than the button, it moves toward the left.

Essentially I'm asking how to justify a button in it's column.

Also, the labels below it is also centred in this column. I'm hoping that whatever I do to the button, I can do to the label and fix both.

Here's what I'm looking at:
[image: Here's what I'm looking at]

Here's the code for creating the back buttons:

```
    self.backButtons = {}
    for frame in self.frames:
        if frame != 'Menu':
            self.backButtons[frame] = tk.Button(self.frames[frame], command = lambda: self.raiseFrame('Menu'), text = '< - - -', bg='black', fg = 'white', width=20, height=5)
            self.backButtons[frame].grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

And here's where the labels are made:

```
self.tableColumns = {
        'Username':self.handle,
        'Performace Points':'{0}pp'.format(round(float(self.stats['pp_raw']),2)),
        'Global Rank':'#{0}'.format(self.stats['pp_rank']),
        'Country Rank':'#{0}'.format(self.stats['pp_country_rank']),
        'Accuracy':'{0}%'.format(round(float(self.stats['accuracy']),2),'%'),
        'Highest PP Play':'{0}pp'.format(round(float(self.topPlay),2)),
        'Playcount':self.stats['playcount'],
        'Time Since Joined':secondConversion(self.stats['join_date'])}

    index = 0
    for i in self.tableColumns:

        self.label = tk.Label(self.statFrame, text = ('{0}: {1}'.format(i, self.tableColumns[i])), fg = 'white', bg = 'gray', font=("Verdana", 16))
        self.label.grid(row = index+3,column = 0)
        index += 1
```

I've tried adding `justify = 'left'` and `anchor = 'w'` to the creation line of the buttons and labels which is what's commonly suggested but it didn't work. Maybe I'm adding it in the wrong place or doing it wrong.

Comment: Add `sticky=tk.W` to `grid(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I tried using sticky before but I didn't use 'tk.' before the w and it resulted in an error.

Comment: I prefer to use the string method with sticky and most other places that can use `tk.` or a string. This way the code always works with `import as tk` and `import *`. So you can also use `sticky='w'` to get the same results.